# How to add observer for view frame change in swift

Tags: swift, view

I added gravity behavior for a view and I need to detect when this view intersects with another view. I need to observe changes of this view's coordinates so that i can detect intersect with this line of code:

```
if (carView.frame.intersects(self.carImageView.frame)) {
        print ("it collides")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle it the view controller methods:

`viewWillLayoutSubviews` - called to notify the view controller that its view is about to layout its subviews.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` - called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.

Or you could handle it by the KVO (Key Value Observing).

Also, you can inherit UIView class and override function `layoutSubviews`.